# Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxObj is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxObj is not definednewsletter @
>   main.js:22onclick @ index.php:541

I am trying to develop a newsletter which will be on the footer part of the every page and it will use NAME and EMAIL to suscribe. It will grab the data entered by user from HTML form and pass it to ajax for validation after usere click submit which will pass information to newsletter.php and give back message to user if they already exist or signup sucessfull message but what happened is as User click submit button it just says "Please wait.." and keeps on loading forever giving above message on chrome cousole.
I want user to be able to sign up from any page they are on without reloading page. 
The problem here is
Above Error given in Chrome cousole while I try to submit the form.

Thank you for looking at my problem. Any help will be appriciated..

HTML

```
  <?php include_once('newsletter.php'); ?>
        <form name="signupform" id="signupform" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
            <p align="center"><strong>NEWSLETTER SIGNUP :</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input id="sus_name" name="sus_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Name" size="15">
            <input id="sus_email" name="sus_email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email" size="26">
            <input id="optin" name="optin" type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" onclick="newsletter()"><br>
            <span id="status"></span>
            </p>
        </form>
```

AJAX

```
//News Letter Validation
function newsletter(){
    var u = document.getElementById("sus_name").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("sus_email").value;
    var m =(document.URL);

    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    if(u == "" || e == ""){
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("optin").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST","(document.URL)");//Problem with this line as i want it to post to same page where url will be dynamic
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {

                if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){

                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("optin").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    document.getElementById("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> ";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e);
    }
}
```

newsletter.php

```
<?php
$msg_to_user = "";
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once "includes/mysqli_connect.php";
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
    $u = ereg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    $e = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['e']);
    // GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = ereg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    if (($u != "") && ($e != "") ){

    // Be sure to filter this data to deter SQL injection, filter before querying database
    $name = $u;
    $email = $e;

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news_letter WHERE susc_email='$email'");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if (!$email) {

        $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="#FFFFFF">Please type an email address ' . $name . '.</font></h4>';

    } else if ($numRows > 0) {

        $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="#FFFFFF">' . $email . ' is already in the system.</font></h4>';

    } else {

        $i= substr($name,0,3);
        $j=rand(1000,9999);
        $l= substr($email,0,3);

        $k= $i.$j.$l;
        $o=rand(0,9);
        $m=str_replace("@","$o","$k");
        $n=mysql_real_escape_string($m);


        $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news_letter (susc_name, susc_email, susc_date, susc_code) 
                                                    VALUES('$name','$email',now(),'$n')")  or die (mysql_error());

        $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="#FFFFFF">Thanks ' . $name . ', you have been added successfully.</font></h4>';
        echo "signup_success";
        exit();
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: The error message is clear. `ajaxObj` is not defined. Are you missing an include? Wrong order of includes?

Comment: Thank you but how can I do that? I am not that much familiar with ajax.

Comment: [AJAX - Getting Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started), [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)